# Apache kafka Setup on windows getting error #

Tags: apache-kafka

When I start the server with below command its showing below error, java path and all are good still showing like this please help with this issue.

> D:\Softwares\kafka\kafka-0.10.0.0-src>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat
>   .\config\server.properties '#' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Could not
>   find or load main class kafka.Kafka

Answer (score 1):

Taking a leap here, but you directory ends in *src*. Mine does not. Any chance you downloaded the source distribution instead of the binary ?

Comment: Thank you #Maximus, your right!!!! I downloaded kafka src file instead of binary...... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

for more recent version, juts define the CLASSPATH in 
 ./bin.windows/kafka-run-class.bat:
line 17 for example

set CLASSPATH=/confluent-5.3.1.TAR\share\java\kafka*